# PHP write data from HTML to text file

Tags: php

I need to write some data from HTML form to **data.txt** file (the txt file have 777 permissions)

The HTML that I use is **index.html**:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<input name="field1" type="text" />
<input name="field2" type="text" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
```

And the PHP file is **index.php**:

```
<?php
$txt = "data.txt"; 
if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) { // check if both fields are set
    $fh = fopen($txt, 'a'); 
    $txt=$_POST['field1'].' - '.$_POST['field2']; 
    fwrite($fh,$txt); // Write information to the file
    fclose($fh); // Close the file
}
?>
```

But when I use the form to save the data, it show me a message box to download the **index.php**

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you visit index.php without going through the form? Sounds like apache (or whatever you are using as a web server) is not configured to serve PHP.

Comment: If using apache2 as your web server, check /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/. It should contain php5.load and php5.conf. If not check if /etc/apache2/mods-available has those files. If not install php5 apache module.